# How do I find the determinant of a permutation matrix that interchanges rows of an $n \times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant

> Let $T_n$ be the permutation matrix that interchanges rows of an $n \times n$ matrix in the following way: row $j$ is moved to row $j + 1$ for $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, n − 1\}$ and the last row is moved to the first. Find $\det(T_3)$.

I really don't know where to start with this problem, I tried to think of a $3 \times 3$ matrix and just follow the interchanges, but I'm not sure if that's the right of way of solving this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you find this matrix $T_3$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You’re on the right track. Try working out the parity of the permutation for small values of $n$ and try to spot a pattern.

Comment: What is the inverse of a permutation matrix?

Comment: Just count the number of row swaps and see if it's odd or even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re on the right track. The permutation matrix that effects this rearrangement is itself the corresponding permutation of the identity matrix.

Start by swapping the last two rows. This moves row $n$ up one space and row $n-1$ down one space into its final position. Proceeding up the rows, continue to swap adjacent rows in turn. Eventually, the last row will have migrated to the top and all the other rows moved down by one, as required. This took $n-1$ swaps, therefore $\det(T_n)=\dots$?

Comment: So would the determinant of all of the permutation matrices just be 1? Is that all there is to this problem?

Comment: @ArataKaizaki Not quite. Since you make $n-1$ swaps, the determinant is equal to $(-1)^{n-1}$. But otherwise, yes, that’s all there is to it.

Comment: Oh ok, I forgot that swapping rows changes the sign of the determinant. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It is a circulant permutation matrix. (The eigenvalues of a known permutation are well determined. Here $1$, $i$ and $-i$ are the three eigenvalues. ) You could figure the signature of a permutation as it is the determinant.